# Android Studio 1.01: Can't launch the Messages window

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm converting from Eclipse to Android Studio 1.01 (on Windows 7) and I wanted to see my compile errors in a clickable form that would take me to where they were in the source code in the IDE editor.   It has been indicated to me that this is done in the Messages window,

But when I go to **View > Tool Windows**, the Messages option is grayed out.    Likewise, if I hover over the icon on the bottom left of the IDE there is no "Messages" option at all, even though apparently it's there for other users.

How do I fix this so I can display my Messages window?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade The Android Studio Version Then Reset The IDE SETTINGS